# Golang struct field vs slice semantics: "has a" slice of structs vs "is a" slice of structs

Tags: go, struct

I have the following struct representing a Webpage

```
type Webpage struct {
    url.URL
    references []url.URL
}
```

I want to represent a website as a collection of Webpages. I am using this struct, but it does not feel like what I am looking for:

```
type website struct {
    []Webpage
}
```

I read this as "a website *has* a slice of Webpages". I want a type that represents "a website *is* a slice of Webpages".

What type do I use to represent the *is* relationship instead of the *has* relationship of a struct field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
type Website []Webpage
```

`Website` is slice of `Webpage`

Comment: yes thanks, so stupid of me. I was just lost somewhere.

Comment: can I have method associated with type Website like I can have with structs?

Comment: At fist I thougt thats not possible. But it works !! https://play.golang.org/p/hcXlqgGho9U.

Answer (score 1):

Of course that's possible. Your structs should be like this.

```
type Webpage struct {
  url        url.URL
  references []url.URL
}

type Website struct {
  webpages []Webpage
}
```

So the `Website` will contain a slice of `Webpages`.
This is common concept while handling with database. If you want to take more example and learn more about the concept you may take a look to this [GORM Documentation](http://doc.gorm.io/associations.html#has-many)

Hope it helps.

Edit:
On the book that you follow, there already provided example: https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/9#section3

```
type MultiShape struct {
    shapes []Shape
}
```

Comment: That i knew, my question was like for Webpage struct I have all my url method available, it has "is-a" relationship not "has-a" relationship, similarly it possible for Website struct with has list of Webpages with "is-a" relationship.

Off-topic: you got a nice name !

Comment: Sorry my bad, misslead by your code example before. I think the answer from @BahNahNah is the correct answer with your question "a Website is a list of Webpage(s)"